# Frustrated TGV Lyria experience

Tags: trains, france, sncf

I would like to share my TGV Lyria experince and see if my complaint is reasonable.

A few month ago I was traveling from Paris to Zurich and I missed my train. I bought the standard ticket which could not be exchanged once the train departed. I was maybe 2 minutes late and they didn't allow me to pass the gate. I went to the custom service and then the train departed. Later I argued with them and they insisted that I should buy another ticket. I ended up paying two fixed tickets for this trip. From this I learned that next time if I know I would miss the train I should stop running and quickly exchange the ticket for free in the app.

This was not the complaint because today something even more frustrated happened:

So my friend planned to come visit me this weekend from Paris to Zurich. I bought one ticket for him on the OUI.sncf app and sent him the screenshot of the ticket. He missed the train exactly the way I did (saw the train there but couldn't enter the gate). Later that day there was another train and he went to the custom service and he was asked to buy another ticket. He paid the same money (130 euro) and bought a ticket for later time.

When he chatted with me about this I was very upset because it happened again. I went to the app and trying to figure out how to complaint. And then I saw that I could click my ticket and refund and it worked?! I chatted with my friend and said "no worry I refunded my ticket and only 30 euro was lost." At this time my friend was still waiting in the train station for the next train. Later he scaned his new ticket for the new train and it didn't work (I didn't know how he bought the new ticket), the people on the gate let him through.

Things seemed a bit positive until later that time my friend called me that he was asked by the ticket inspector on the train that his ticket was invalid due to refund? I started realizing that the ticket on my app was my friend's new ticket. We both thought it was my old expired ticket. The conversatoin with the ticket inspectors were not so successful, they assumed my friend intented to skip a ticket. They tried charging him 240 euro (I guess it's full fare maybe plus fine). The credit card machine was not working after 4th or 5th tries and they assumed my friend's credit card had no money. They asked my friend's passport and address and said that they would send the fine by mail and maybe put it on some record. My friend asked them repeatedly to provide another credit card machine and in the end one of the inspector found one and charged in CHF instead, they charged 299 CHF (209 CHF for full fare and 90 CHF for maybe fine). My friend later kept asking them whether they remove the record and the ticket inspector said yes.

The whole thing was so frustrated that I just keep thinking about it. I admitted there are issues on our side (late for train, clicked refund button). But I still felt something wrong here:

1. For my train experience in Switzerland/Italy/Germany I didn't see that you cannot quickly exchange the ticket when you are just late to catch the train. Also for flights it happens as well. I know the terms are written on the ticket but still I feel it wrong and a fully flexible ticket is 50 euro more and the only thing it does it's that you can exchange free 2 hours after it departs.
2. It's my mistake that I didn't check what ticket I was refunding. The fact is that I couldn't tell. The code was the same and only the time updated and which I missed. (update) My refund was sucessful before the train depart so my friend was using a refunded ticket and couldn't pass the gate, he didn't know his ticket was refunded and asked the people there and they let him through. From this I think it's not just our mistake and they also didn't check carefully and they have a gate!
3. For this trip due to all the frustrated things we've at least paid 130 (1st ticket) + 30 (refund fee) and we still didn't have a valid ticket and had to pay 299CHF on the train. And the inspector was like oh you didn't have a ticket and I would let you pay. I know it's their jobs but I would be less upset if they could try to understand what happened and not treated us as someone who didn't want to buy a ticket. It was my fault and I was very upset for the trouble caused to my friend.

I post here just want to hear your opinion/suggestion and maybe more objective. After talking to my friend my claims are more clear now:

1. Confirm there is not any sort of record as we were not intent to skip a ticket. And besides we are allowed to go on the train with an invalid ticket (which we were not aware of) and this was not our fault.
2. As we were not intent to skip a ticket I would like to request removal of fine. I would be ok to pay the extra 130 euro due to our mistakes but 299 CHF was too much.
3. My friend was treated very bad by those two ticket inspectors who might just do their job. I would like to ask some sort of apologies but honestly I think it would be hard.

---

Thanks for all the comments and after syncing with my friend I've made it clear my claim and updated the above text. I would reach out to them and see what would happen.

---

Sep 21, 2021:

Just want to give you some update that I reached out to TGV Lyria custom services and they did reply and

1. Confirmed there was no fine/record as the fine was paid on board
2. The fine was paid in CFF but not in SNCF system so that they could not remove the fine easily and instead they offered some 100 CHF vouchers.
3. They acknowledged my feedback and would share the feedback with the team.

I think it's great that I heard from them and they acknowledged that it was (largely my) mistake but not intention.

Thank you all for the feedback and thanks TGV Lyria for the response.

Comment: What were the terms of the ticket? They were nearly certainly explicit shown to you before booking, and possibly written on the ticket itself. If you were both late and the tickets were not exchangeable/refundable after departure, it’s perfectly normal you had to buy new tickets, as you were no shows. You didn’t want to pay more for flexible tickets which could have been exchanged or refunded after departure, the same thing would have happened with equivalent fares on any other train company or airline.

Comment: I usually bought ticket on the app and I did understand the term and it clearly says not exchangeable/refundable after departure. So +50 euros for 2h flexiable is totally normal?

Comment: What, in your opinion, did the train company do wrong, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for both your comments. It's true the train company didn't do wrong. I'm just wondering if such things happen to someone would he or she should just admit it. Or maybe they would not get to this if they always watch/plan well. If I should say one thing was that the ticket inspector was not so nice (but I was on the phone not in person so hard to explain to him).

Comment: €50 sounds about right, more in first class but you can check the fares on https://www.oui.sncf/ so what is actually your question?

Comment: I think my current question would be to confirm there was not record (minimum request, as we were not intented to skip a ticket) and requested an apologize for the treatment that my friend got.

Comment: Note that it is a common scam for people to board the train and then cancel tickets which allow cancellation after departure (flexible fares allow you to do so online within 30 or 45 minutes or so of departure), hoping not to be checked on board (which is more frequent when there is a check before boarding). I've seen people do so, try to plead an error, but be faced by a wall. Having a cancelled ticket is the same as having no ticket at all, and usually results in a fine.

Comment: My opinion is that you shouldn't buy fixed-time tickets anymore.  The flex-time tickets exist for a reason.  They're a bit more expensive, but I'm guessing they're nowhere near as expensive as buying two fixed-time tickets.  Trains in Europe are non-negotiable on departure time, so if you find it difficult to make it to the gate on time (due to Paris traffic or whatever), buy a flex ticket and take a load off your mind.  I've bought fixed-time tickets before and lived to regret it.  Now I always buy the flex price and don't worry about the unexpected.

Comment: "Note that it is a common scam for people to board the train and then cancel tickets which allow cancellation after departure" I didn't know this and I agree it's hard to prove that we didn't intent to do this. So I booked the ticket for my friend and he bought another ticket when he missed the train, I assumed it was a separate ticket and thus why I tried canceling my ticket. I guess what happened would be my friend tried to ask for exchange and the custom service said no and offered an exchange with full price, which was still the same code.

Comment: Also I just noticed that I canceled the ticket before the depart time so my friend was still in the train station by then. I guess I can cite this as a proof that we did this by mistake. It's pretty much he bought a ticket and after 5 mins or so I canceled the same one and he went to the same train.

Comment: Please do not bold sentences in the main body of the text, that does not help with readability.

Comment: @Willeke sorry but you revert my entire edit, let me redo it without bolding the sentences.

Comment: @code6 There's something I don't understand here. What is the actual timing of departure time / time your friend got to the platform / time they bought the new ticket / time you cancelled the ticket? For TGV (and I believe it's the same for Lyria) the cut-off is 2 minutes before departure, so it's quite unlikely a new ticket could have been bought before departure. What was the fare (type) of the original ticket, and that of the new one?

Comment: @jcaron So we first bought a Paris to Zurich direct TGV Lyria train which departed at 16:22 and my friend got to the platform at around 16:20 or 16:21 and the gate was closed. He bought a later direct train which departed at 18:22. I canceled the ticket at 17:35 and was successful (I received an email confirmation) at 18:12. For the fare type both ticket are 2nd class standard fare (not exchangable / refundable after departure).

Comment: Ah OK I had thought for a minute you meant you cancelled it before the original departure time. Basically that means they stepped onto the train without a ticket… In France if you step into the train without a ticket and don’t go see the train manager right away, and they only find out when they check tickets, it’s a violation and a fine is due.

Comment: @jcaron for our case we didn't know we didn't have a valid ticket and thus why we didn't think about reaching out to the train manager. And I think for TGV Lyria there is a gate that you need to scan the ticket. So they should have not let my friend through given that he used an invalid ticket which he didn't know, he asked for help and they just let him through.

Comment: @Kyralessa They are not “a bit” more expensive, they are frequently twice as expensive or more. For many people the saver fare is what makes a trip possible (that or a bus or rideshare). Personnally, I can afford it and I would still buy non-flex tickets and eat the difference whenever something goes bad. If you miss one train out of 3, you're still coming out on top. Flex tickets mostly make sense for business travel (it's typically covered by big companies travel rules and you get to hop on the first train after your meeting ends).

Comment: @Relaxed Now that I think about it, you're right.  My wife and I each have a BahnCard 50 in Germany, so flex rates are 50% off for us.  Of course, an irregular traveler or a tourist wouldn't have that.  Regular non-discounted rates are indeed quite a bit more expensive than the fixed-time rates, not merely double the rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, you are unlikely to get anything for the trains you missed. I know people who got lucky by pleading their case with a Thalys employee on the platform but this all seems in line with SNCF rules and practices.

Note that if you were able to pay for a ticket on the train, the train guard was in fact showing some understanding for your situation. If they didn't, they can impose a €50 fine on top of the regular fare (more if they suspect deliberate fraud). Legally, this €50 fee is an actual fine (*contravention* in French), which can be collected by the French tax office (unlike, e.g., fees imposed by banks or utilities).

It's true that it can be frustrating and that train travel works differently in different European countries (or even between different operators or different types of trains) but that's not going to change the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to check with my friend for whether there was a fine. It seemed he had to pay more but I need to double check. Well again it might be hard to challenge.

Comment: @code6 If there was a fine there is a slim chance to get it removed. Be apologetic, insist that it was an honest mistake and that you are happy to pay the full price of the fare as evidenced by your other purchases, etc. Don't dwell on the fact that you were only late by x min, could still see the train or that it works differently in Germany or anything like that.

Comment: I just synced with my friend and he did pay more (300 CHF) and the ticket inspector was taking his passport and threating to add some record. According to my friend they (two of them) were hard to communiate with and assumed he intented to not buy a ticket. I will talk to the custom service and try to phrase as you suggested.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, I understand your frustration but I don't see what the train company has done wrong.

1. You were late. If you are not at the boarding gate at the gate closing time or on the platform at departure time there is no obligation to wait.
2. If you have a fixed time ticket and you don't show the ticket is invalidated as spelled out in the terms on conditions that you signed and agreed to when you bought the ticket. If you don't like this terms, you need to buy a flex ticket. Yes, it's substantially more expensive, but it also represents more value.
3. You cancelled and refunded the wrong ticket.

What exactly do you think the train company did wrong here? Do you feel that there are any rules or terms of the contract that they didn't adhere to?

> but I would try to reach out to the custom service team to see what would happen.

In all likelihood nothing would happen. They will simply ignore it or maybe send you an automatic form letter along the lines "we are sorry you had a bad experience, we'll try to do better next time".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I totally agree with what you said. 

For "What exactly do you think the train company did wrong here? Do you feel that there are any rules or terms of the contract that they didn't adhere to?" yeah I don't seem to have valid claim.

Comment: I've updated my claim and identified one thing I think they did wrong, they have a gate and they allowed my friend to pass the gate with an already refunded ticket. We didn't know the ticket was refunded and I think this was their mistake, they should have identified and told my friend that the ticket was invalid.

Answer (score 7):

What went wrong here is you bought "the cheap seats" and did not read or understand the terms and conditions, aka the "fine print", or think all that much about *what makes them* the "cheap seats".

> a fully flexible ticket is 50 euro more and the only thing it does it's that you can exchange free 2 hours after it departs...

**That feature is specifically for people who like to "shave it really close"** on arriving at the station.  And it doesn't take a whole lot of introspection to realize *that's definitely you* - I bet you do that all the time, have honed it to a fine art, and are even a bit proud of the skill!

Believe me, I know how that can be - so many lovely things to do near train stations in places that are not Ohio, and smart-phone clocks are so accurate that you know exactly the time you have to spare.

So it sounds to me like you were caught off-guard by the early-arrival requirements, and the existence of that flexible ticket didn't sufficiently clue you into the use-case for it.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to train travel France is different from Switzerland. In Switzerland it is perfectly Ok to be on the platform 1 second before the doors close. The conductor will even hold the train a few seconds so you can still get on. And it is normal that tickets can be used on the next train when you miss one. And there are no gates to slow you down from the street to the train.

Buy a TGV ticket in France however, and the ticket says clearly that you have to be on the platform at least three minutes before the train leaves. And Gare de Lyon has gates. And these close a few minutes before departure. So planning to be at the station at the last moment is in France never a good idea.

The railway did not do anything wrong here. This is just a case of certain expectations not being met by reality.

Comment: Are you certain this text appears on the ticket?  I looked for images of TGV train tickets but I couldn't find one that stated (in French or anything else) that one has to be at the platform 3 minutes before departure.

Comment: Yes I did see that the ticket on the app explicitly mentioned that we need to board 2 mins before departure. And indeed we get used to trains in switzerland as normally long distance train you pretty much get a ticket for the whole day and you can take whatever train suitable for you. And there is not gate at all. 

For what the railway did wrong I think they assumed we intented to skip a ticket and did fine us 300 CHF on the train (and threatened a record). This might be as well as regular practice but I find it too hard to accept and I will challenge this.

Comment: Even in Switzerland, there are tickets which are only valid on a specific train. If you miss it, you can't hop on the next one without buying a new ticket. In France this varies with the type of train, but all TGV services have compulsory reservation and all TGV tickets are associated with a specific train.

Comment: These supersaver tickets are however a recent thing, and most people still buy tickets they expect to be useable on any train on a route.